# Read and Unread Message feature

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create Read and Unread Message feature in my chat application.

So far I can create only Unread, which means when I send Message to firebase collection, I decleared my
`READ` property  field as  `FALSE`,

I am confused how the second user will change the value of the "READ: TRUE" back if he checks the chat room, and if the second user is currently in the chat room he should still change the READ: true.

here is the my send message data:

```
    sender_id:12233,
    reciever_id: 6767,
    message:'hello please help',
    read: false,
```

here is my code

```
StreamBuilder(
                      stream: firestore
                          .collection('chat')
                          .doc(widget.peerid)
                          .collection('Messages')
                          .snapshots(),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          return Center(
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          );
                        }
                        if (snapshot.data.docs.isEmpty) {
                          return Center(
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  child: Icon(
                                    FontAwesomeIcons.comments,
                                    size: 40,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  'Say Hello',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 15,
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          );
                        }
                        return ListView.builder(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              final authid =
                                  snapshot.data.docs[index].data()['idFrom'];
                              final msg =
                                  snapshot.data.docs[index].data()['content'];
                              bool check =
                                  authid == auth.currentUser.uid ? true : false;
                              return Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  horizontal: 15,
                                  vertical: 10,
                                ),
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: check
                                      ? CrossAxisAlignment.end
                                      : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Container(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        color: check
                                            ? Colors.indigo
                                            : Colors.white,
                                        borderRadius: check
                                            ? BorderRadius.only(
                                                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                                                topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                                                topRight: Radius.circular(30),
                                              )
                                            : BorderRadius.only(
                                                bottomRight:
                                                    Radius.circular(30),
                                                topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                                                topRight: Radius.circular(30),
                                              ),
                                      ),
                                      child: ConstrainedBox(
                                        constraints:
                                            BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 150),
                                        child: Column(
                                          children: [
                                            Text(
                                              msg,
                                              style: GoogleFonts.raleway(
                                                textStyle: TextStyle(
                                                  color: check
                                                      ? Colors.white
                                                      : Colors.black,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            Text('')
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              );
                            });
                      }),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: Platform.isIOS ? 95 : 80,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius:
                      BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(70)),
                  color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
                ),
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(
                    Icons.add,
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  ),
                  title: TextFormField(
                    controller: messagesController,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      messagesController.text = value;
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Enter your messgae here...',
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                    ),
                    maxLines: null,
                  ),
                  trailing: messagesController.text.trim() == null
                      ? Container(
                          width: 40,
                          height: 45,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            gradient: LinearGradient(
                              begin: Alignment.topRight,
                              end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                              colors: [
                                Constants.color1,
                                Constants.color2,
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () async {
                              await ControllerApi().sendMessage(
                                content: messagesController.text.trim(),
                                chatID: widget.peerid,
                                messageType: 'text',
                                myID: auth.currentUser.uid,
                                selectedUserID: widget.userid,
                              );
                            },
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.send,
                              size: 20,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      : Container(),
                ),
              )
            ],
```

Thanks.

Comment: there will be a chat id i guess where both interact with each other. :)

Comment: yes... i peer the two id together to create the collection

Comment: initially add false if receiver seen then true then both will know its true..

Comment: i dont understand your last comment, can you explain better?

Comment: When second user loads his messages from stream to his chat screen, you `.map` a function on each snapshot that set `Read` field to TRUE if its value equals FALSE.

Comment: @SimonSot i really dont understand what you said but let me update my question with my full code.....

Comment: @SimonSot i have update my question with full code

Comment: You only need to validate if your current user logged has the same id as `sender_id` so you don't need update the `read` value.

Comment: @GbengaBAyannuga please consider accepting the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) that helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let's write a function that marks the opponent's messages as read.

```
Future<void> seeMsg(int peerId) async{
     final query = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('chat')
        .doc(peerId)
        .collection('Messages')
        .where('sender_id', isEqualTo: peerId)
        .where('read', isEqualTo: false)
        .get();

    query.docs.forEach((doc) {
      doc.reference.update({'read': true});
    });
}
```

Then, call this function inside `StreamBuilder` body.
Every time, a new message is generated inside this chat collection, this function checks for unread messages from your peer and marks them as read.

Comment: can you please look at the question code and update this answer to the question please.

Comment: can you please check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75220565/how-to-do-when-msg-is-readed-then-color-is-change-or-msg-is-nor-read-its-color

Comment: Hi I would like to ask, I wonder if I has 10 new messages, so I need to do looping for updating the flag read from false to true, is doing looping 10 times good to go ? I have the same case like this and open my own question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78105050/the-structure-of-firestore-database-for-storing-chat-and-read-unread-status

Answer (score 1):

Generally, it's not correct to keep this mark in the same table.
Because you need to add access rights sender and receiver to change all messages.
Better solution is to create another table something like _metadata and keep this mark there.

Comment: give your own sample code, if you are suggesting a better solution

Answer (score 0):

Inside your chat app, when you load messages to user, lets say you already have loaded messages and have a `List<Message> messages`.
Lets say you show messages with `ListView.builder`:

```
return ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                controller: _controller,
                reverse: true,
                itemCount: messages.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final message = messages[index];
                  // We check if message is new (dont know your entity so lets say it has boolean `read`, that false when new.
                  final bool isNew = !message.read;
                  // Given that you store your fire id in myId variable we check if message is received and not sent.
                  final bool toMe = message.recieverId == myId;
                  // Check that we need to mark message as read
                  if (isNew && toMe) {
                    return FutureBuilder<void>(
                        future: markAsRead(), // markAsRead is a Future function to change your FIELD value in firestore.
                         builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                              ConnectionState.done) {
                            return YourMessageWidgetThatWasSeen()
                            }
                            return YourMessageWidgetThatWasNotSeen();}); //FutureBuilder ends here.
                  return MessageBubble(); // or this message is already seen by user and we return message bubble like usually do.
```

`markAsRead()` function implementation depends on what structure your database has, for example when your each user has its own collection of messages to store, AND if you have a collections for a dialog preview with last message shown, you will need to create a batch with 4 update operations in it.

Comment: i am getting it now... so i will only make a futureBuilder to change the bool like return FutureBuilder<void>(
                        future: firebase.collection('chat').doc(peerid).update({read: 'true'}); or what i dont get. because futurebuilder accept .get()

Comment: please can you show me the full code that answer.. so that i will be very clear please

Comment: @GbengaBAyannuga about future yes you got the idea, `FirebaseFirestore.instance..collection('chat').doc(peerid).update({read: 'true'});`

Comment: okay i will try now and i will get back to you. please how can i get you for quick access.. because my system is low now

Comment: @GbengaBAyannuga I need to work too, write here, im checking SO on regular basis.

Comment: hello.. is saying i cant use update with future

Comment: "The method 'update' isn't defined for the type 'CollectionReference'.\nTry correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'update'."

Comment: this code final bool toMe = message.recieverId == myId.... myid is which id, is it sender id or what id ?...and  update cant be use in Futurebuilder

Comment: @GbengaBAyannuga its `reciever_id` field in your database. You need to change status of message when they are recieved, this is this boolean for.

Comment: okay.. i get that part but now... update cant work with futurebuilder

Comment: @GbengaBAyannuga then something isnt right, because this code is from my chat app and its working. It  saiing update function is not defined?

Comment: @GbengaBAyannuga by the way I hope you got that I mistyped and one dot there is off? `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('chat').doc(peerid).update({read: 'true'});` I can't edit old comments, thought that you will get that there is one dot after `instance` word..

Comment: i have try to use update.. is not working... FutureBuilder doesnt work with future.... i fully understand the process... i think i can make it as function like @Ehsan Askari said in the answer....

Comment: @GbengaBAyannuga FutureBuilder doesnt work with future.... Try another solution if that will work for you. Wish you luck.

Comment: i mean future doesnt work with update.... that is typo error

Answer (score 0):

Use this flutter library
[visibility_detector](https://pub.dev/packages/visibility_detector)

Please see the below code, it will help you to implement the read & unread message.

```html
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.separated(
      itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
        ChatModel chatModel =
            ChatModel.fromJson(snapshot.data.docs[index].data());
        switch (chatModel.messageType) {
          case MessageType.TEXT:
            {
              return VisibilityDetector(
                key: Key(snapshot.data.docs[index].id),
                onVisibilityChanged: (VisibilityInfo visibilityInfo) {
                  var visiblePercentage = visibilityInfo.visibleFraction * 100;
                  if (visiblePercentage == 100 &&
                      !chatModel.isSeen &&
                      chatModel.sender != userController.userModel.value.uid) {
                    FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .collection(FirebaseKeys.chatRoom)
                        .doc(AppHelper.getChatID(
                            userController.userModel.value.uid, userModel.uid))
                        .collection(FirebaseKeys.messages)
                        .doc(snapshot.data.docs[index].id)
                        .update({
                      "isSeen": true,
                    });
                  }
                },
                child:
                    TextMessage(chatModel, snapshot.data.docs[index].reference),
              );
            }
          case MessageType.GIF:
            {
              return GifMessage(chatModel, userModel.uid);
            }
          case MessageType.IMAGE:
            {
              return ImageMessage(snapshot.data.docs[index].reference,
                  chatModel, userModel.uid);
            }
          case MessageType.AUDIO:
            {
              break;
            }
          case MessageType.VIDEO:
            {
              break;
            }
          case MessageType.PDF:
            {
              break;
            }
          case MessageType.FILE:
            {
              break;
            }
          case MessageType.OTHER:
            {
              break;
            }
        }
        return FlutterLogo();
      },
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
      controller: scrollController,
      reverse: true,
      physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
      separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Container(
          height: 5,
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2, bottom: 2),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: this userController.userModel.value.uid is which id ?

Comment: userController.userModel.value.uid is login user UID