# the structure of firestore database for storing chat and read unread status

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing room chat by using flutter. I have already made a structure of firestore database to store chat, here is it :
`messages` collection :

- room chat X to Y :

  - dttm 1 (date and time message has sent)

    - content message
    - id sender
    - id receiver
    - dttm
    - isRead
  - dttm 2 (date and time message has sent)

    - content message
    - id sender
    - id receiver
    - dttm
    - isRead
  - etc ...

what I make confuse is.. is this the right structure ? because I need to add read and unread status in UI, but lets say user X has 10 new messages from Y, so I need to do looping 10 times to update the `isRead` status from `false` to `true` right ? I am not sure this is the right way to do looping multiple times, is that really good structure of firestore db ? or is there another good way ?

Answer (score 1):

The schema for messages is fine except for the `isRead` field. A better approach can be to create a `ReadStatus` collection to store the pending messages for a user for a particular chat.

Here is a sample schema for `ReadStatus` collection:

- userId: reference
- roomId: reference
- lastReadAt: timestamp
- unreadCount: number

Here instead of looping through the message and updating `isRead` you can just  update the `unreadCount`.

Comment: so I need to make ```ReadStatus``` collection outside ```messages``` collection, right ? but if I do so, I have to do streaming to 2 collections (```messages``` : for doing chatting and ```ReadStatus``` : for labelling status chat)

Comment: Yes. but since there is only 1 record per user per room for ReadStatus it should not be too heavy to execute.

Comment: I got your point, thank you very much for the information I will try it later

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the needs of your specific application, but most apps just  track the last message that the user has read for each chat room. So say that you store the ID of timestamp for `dttm 1`, then you know that everything up to that message has been read, and anything after it has not been read. With this approach you can track the progress of each user in a chat room with a single value.

Comment: I also think the same way like you, but another question show up, what if user X and user Y are in the room chat (they are online and opening chat screen each other) so I need to send the chat message with status flag ```isRead``` directly to ```true``` right ? so I need to differentiate wether user is opening room chat or will open the chat right ?

Comment: In my data model there is no `isRead` boolean on each message, but rather a single `lastRead` (timestamp or message ID) for each user/chat room combination. --- In either model, sending a message indeed will likely (but not necessarily) assume that the user has caught up reading all incoming messages. If you check some of your favorite chat apps, you'll notice that some of them do the same.

Comment: okey I almost got your point, can you tell me more about when and how to update ```lastRead``` when X and Y (both of them are in in the room chat each other) ? are you updating ```lastRead``` (timestamp) right after user sending a reply ?

Comment: so far I have ```dttm``` as time where user sending a message to other

Comment: You need to update the `lastRead` field whenever you want to mark messages as read. So when sending it, you'd indeed set it to the ID/timestamp of the new message, but when displaying messages you'd **also** update it to the last message that is displayed on screen.

Comment: thank you very much for giving your insight, I will try it